# X-Editable & Backbone model previousAttributes()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, x-editable

***What I have:***

I have x-editable popup which should check input parameters with help of validate method

```
$(".vacancy-edit-select-status").editable({
    value: $this.model.get('value').id,
    source: source,
    validate: function(value) {
        $this.model.previousAttributes(); //UNDEFINED!!!
        //....            
    },
    success: function (response, newValue) {
        $this.model.set('value', newValue);
    }
});
```

***What a problem:***

Inside validate method *previousAttributes()* method return 'undefined'. (I've changed some model attributes before change x-editable popup's variables, so the history shouldn't be empty)

***Question:***

How can I access *model* history from *validate* method?

Answer (score 1):

`previousAttributes` populating during `set`, `validate`  calling before population of `previousAttributes` - [reference](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-40)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple and maybe not clear enough from my question:

*Backbone clones model state* ***only on change event***.

Moreover, when you have a collection as an model attribute there are also some ***nuances with  previousAttributes***. For example, to write attribute change to the history ***you have to rewrite the whole attribute***. I mean

```
this.model.get('myCommentsCollection').push('newComment'); //DOESN'T WRITE ANYTHING TO previousAttributes
```

So to write something to *model.previousAttributes* you should do:

```
var comments = _.clone(this.model.get("comments"));
this.model.set('myCommentsCollection', comments);
```